# Access File creating Excel With MessageBox

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, msgbox

I've gotten my Access File pulling data from a database and turning it over into excel files that are auto generated and emailed. What I can't figure out is how to make the excel file have a message box pop up upon closing the excel file. I know this is possible to do as I've done it many times on regular excel files.

I believe that the issue is within the access file only generating .xlsx files and not .xlsm files. OR that the VBA code I am trying to use isn't proper (either in the placing of the code or the code itself.

If you can solve it and are wondering what should the message box say, I would simply like a "Have you complete the task?" Yes/No box nothing crazy.

```
FilePath = "\\ms000ew01\Departments\Reporting\Reports"
FileName = FilePath & "\" & GrName & ShipDate & Timestamp
Attachfile = FileName & ".xlsm"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Draft", 
FileName, True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Turn", 
FileName, True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Final", 
FileName, True

Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlApp
    .Visible = False
    .Workbooks.Open (FileName & ".xlsm")
    .Sheets("Draft").Select
    .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Size = 8
    xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    xlApp.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    .Sheets("Turn").Select
     .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Size = 8
    xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    xlApp.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
     .Sheets("Final").Select
     .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Size = 8
    xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    xlApp.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim MailObj As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailObj = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With MailObj
.To = EmailTo
.Subject = GrName & " Report"
.Body = "Attached is your report"
.Attachments.Add Attachfile
.Send
End With

Set OutApp = Nothing
Set MailObj = Nothing
rst.MoveNext

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please include the code in your question and format it as code block (intend it at least 4 spaces).

Comment: Can you please paste some code?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  `XLSX` files cannot contain VBA code.  You would need to generate `XLSM`.  Also, images of code are hard to read and impossible for anyone else to run; copied text pasted as a code block is preferred. Please check out the [tour] (you'll earn a badge!) and also se "[ask]" as well as [mcve].  There are more good tips from [so]'s top user [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Oh okay! I changed it up and I'll take a look at the tour as well. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is code in access file?

Comment: Yes. The access file creates the excel file.

Comment: Maybe try diffrent approach? Create xlsm file with code you need manualy. Save it in access file location. Than export data to this xlsm file (remember to delete old data).

Comment: The issue with that is that this file goes to multiple people and I cannot force all of them to do this every time. This was simply a fail safe to ensure that they are all completing the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy code to newly created workbooks' ThisWorkbook module (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119646/copy-code-to-newly-created-workbooks-thisworkbook-module-vba)

Comment: Since the Access file is manipulating the data then creating the excel files I can't simply pull the data straight into the excel file.

Comment: In order to do what you describe, the Access code would need to write other code into the XLSM. This is an entire branch of its own in the VBA coding world. You would need an project reference to `VBIDE` aka `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility`. To give you an idea of the direction you need to go in, refer to Chip Pearson's (RIP!) pages on VBA code writing other VBA code: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx. I am currently in the process of working this out for a project of my own, with a twist. Access adding button event code to the Excel VBA module. But not done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The code listed below was updated on Monday 7/16/18 to reflect the work I've done on it since this original post last week. The new code is fully tested and functional in Office 2007, however it will need to be customized with the proper file names, tables, queries, email addresses, etc. In all, glad I finally got this working, since I've been wanting to programmatically generate Access forms & reports with embedded code.

I'll continue my comment here. To paraphrase, the Access VBA module would need to write new code into the Excel VBA module. In order to allow this, the Access VBA project would need a reference to `VBIDE` aka `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility`. This library allows fairly extensive access for automation of the VBA IDE aka the windows you write code in.

Chip Pearson (who sadly perished in June after a car accident in April) has an excellent collection of pages on coding for VBIDE: [cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx](http://cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx). Unfortunately, I can now find no useful command references for VBIDE on any Microsoft Pages; they seem to have removed all but those for Office 365, and what's left isn't much. This follows on Microsoft's long tradition of under-documentation for VBIDE.

I'm currently in the process of working this out for a project of my own, with a twist. The code that needs to be written is the `Click` event of a button. And to write events with VBIDE (rather than a regular sub or function), a special method must be used: `CreateEventProc`. As I mentioned, my project isn't done yet, but I've hacked this code example together for you. Note this is *not* tested. I will see if I can make this actually work later today. We both seem to have the same goal of using Access VBA to create Excel workbooks and then write VBA into them, so I'm motivated to make it work...

```
Public Function CreateExcelWorkbookWithEvents()

    'This procedure is meant to reside in a Microsoft Access code module.

    'This procedure requires two project references:
    ' 1) Microsoft Excel   XX.Y Object Library (mine is 12.0)
    ' 2) Microsoft Outlook XX.Y Object Library (mine is 12.0)
    ' 3) Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility X.Y (mine is 5.3)

    'Project references are always preferred over CreateObject() when possible, since a
    'reference allows the IntelliSense auto-complete to do its job. Otherwise, it's
    'coding blind, and that's just no fun.

    'Access variables.
    Dim acc         As Access.Application
    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsRows      As Long
    Dim sqlText     As String

    'Excel variables.
    Dim xl          As Excel.Application
    Dim wb          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wss         As Excel.Sheets
    Dim ws          As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws1         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws3         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim firstCell   As String

    'VBIDE variables.
    Dim proj        As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim comp        As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim cmod        As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim code        As String

    'Outlook variables.
    Dim olapp       As Outlook.Application
    Dim olmsg       As Outlook.MailItem

    'Other variables.
    Dim filepath        As String
    Dim filename        As String
    Dim fileext         As String
    Dim fullFilename    As String
    Dim timestamp       As String

    'Filename construction.
    filepath = "c:\windows\temp"
    filename = "MyWb"
    fileext = "xlsm"
    timestamp = VBA.Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss")
    fullFilename = filepath & "\" & filename & "_" & timestamp & "." & fileext

    'Access objects.
    Set acc = Access.Application
    Set db = acc.CurrentDb

    'Excel objects.
    Set xl = New Excel.Application

    'Create a new blank WB with one worksheet. The 'xlWBATWorksheet' parameter creates a
    'new blank workbook with only one sheet instead of the usual three. A weird side
    'effect of this is the workbook will have the name "Sheet1" instead of "Book1", but
    'otherwise it's a perfectly normal workbook.
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    'Uncomment and change text if desired.
    'xl.Caption = "Workbook Title"

    'Add & name the tabs.
    Set wss = wb.Worksheets
    Set ws1 = wss(1)
    ws1.name = "tmpDraft"
    Set ws2 = wss.Add(, wss(wss.Count), , xlWorksheet)
    ws2.name = "tmpTurn"
    Set ws3 = wss.Add(, wss(wss.Count), , xlWorksheet)
    ws3.name = "tmpFinal"
    ws1.Select 'Go back to the first sheet.

    'Loop through worksheets, use tab names for the queries, dump the data into the sheets,
    'then format them as desired.
    firstCell = "A1" 'Where to put data on each sheet.
    For Each ws In wss
        sqlText = "SELECT * FROM " & ws.name & ""
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlText, dbOpenSnapshot, dbFailOnError)
        rsRows = ws.Range(firstCell).CopyFromRecordset(rs) 'This
        Set rs = Nothing
        ws.Cells.Font.name = "Tahoma"
        ws.Cells.Font.size = 8
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Next

    'Add the event code. Build the code in a way that's easy to read. Because there are
    'of embedded double-quotes in the strings, this part can get quite messy and
    'difficult to read. So that's why VBA.Replace() is used. It makes the "code of code"
    'much more freindly to human eyes. The code that's built here is only what's
    'between Sub...End Sub, which are created automatically by CreateEventProc().
    '
    'Just as in Microsoft Word, the paragraph character  indicates where a
    'hard-return should be, but something offbeat had to be used to show the double
    'quotes, so the degree symbol ° is used, that being Chr$(176). Although any
    'character(s) which the programmer desires may be used, these were chosen because
    'they do not appear as valid characters in VBA.
    '
    'Note: The section of the code below with the If-Then to detect if Excel is visible
    'are needed because the wb.Close statement further down in this subroutine cause the
    'event we just created to be trigged as if the user is attempting to exit Excel. This
    'seemed to be the simplest way to handle this, with other options such as setting
    'a global variable somehow in Excel while the code is being created, but I didn't\
    'experiment with that.
    '
    code = ""
    code = code & "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)¶"
    code = code & "Dim xlapp       As Excel.Application¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgResponse As VbMsgBoxResult¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgTitle    As String¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgText     As String¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgStyle    As Long¶"
    code = code & "¶"
    code = code & "'Detect if Excel is hidden, presumably because it was created via automation¶"
    code = code & "'from another program. If so, do not prompt the user to confirm exit.¶"
    code = code & "Set xlapp = Excel.Application¶"
    code = code & "If xlapp.Visible = True Then¶"
    code = code & "    msgTitle = °Confirm Exit°¶"
    code = code & "    msgText = °Are you sure you want to exit?°¶"
    code = code & "    msgStyle = vbApplicationModal + vbExclamation + vbYesNo¶"
    code = code & "    msgResponse = MsgBox(msgText, msgStyle, msgTitle)¶"
    code = code & "    If msgResponse = vbNo Then¶"
    code = code & "        Cancel = True 'This is what cancels the Close event.¶"
    code = code & "    End If¶"
    code = code & "End If¶"
    code = code & "End Sub¶"
    code = VBA.Replace(code, "¶", vbCrLf)       'Replace the ¶ characters with hard returns.
    code = VBA.Replace(code, "°", VBA.Chr(34))  'Replace the ° characters with double quotes.

    'Dig into the VBA Project, create the event, and add the code. NOTE: There is an
    'issue with manipulating code from VBA. You can't step through those lines in debug
    'mode if you are adding code to the SAME file you're working in. For instance, if you're
    'in an XLSM file, adding code to its own ThisWorkbook module. Won't work. It causes a
    'runtime error. I think Chip Pearson mentioned it on his VBIDE pages, but I can't find it.
    Set proj = wb.VBProject                         'Grab the VBA project.
    Set comp = proj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")    'Grab the "ThisWorkbook" code module.
    Set cmod = comp.CodeModule                      'Grab the ThisWorkbook code window.
    cmod.InsertLines cmod.CountOfLines + 1, code    'Insert the code.

    'Originally CreateEventProc() was used, but it was found to pop open the VBA IDE
    'window, despite any attempt to prevent it. However, the same goal can be accomplished
    'with the regular InsertLines() function. It's all text in the IDE anyways, and how it
    'gets there doesn't matter. One need only be certain everything is spelled correctly.
    'This is the original attempt:
    'xl.vbe.MainWindow.Visible = False               'Hide the VBA editor from the user.
    'firstLine = cmod.CreateEventProc("BeforeClose", "Workbook") + 1 'Create the event.

    'Save as a macro-enabled workbook. Don't forget: each installation of Excel may need
    'the macros enabled in the security settings.
    wb.SaveAs fullFilename, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    'Not sure if this is desired.
    'xl.Visible = True

    'Clear the variables. If the 'xl' variable is not released, lost instances of Excel
    'will start to pile up in memory. They can be seen in Task Manager, but to be properly
    'identified, click View > Select Columns > Command Line > Ok. The instances of Excel
    'started from VBA will have the command line switch '/automation -Embedding' like this:
    '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /automation -Embedding
    'And even so, these instances of Excel may not unload from memory until this subroutine
    'is finished and exits. It's a fussy thing with a difficult pattern to follow. I find if
    'while devloping the code, when stepping through debug with F8, if I stop the macro
    'prematurely, the automation instances tend to stack up and need to be manually killed.
    wb.Close True
    xl.Quit
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing

    'Create the email and send it.
    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olmsg = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olmsg.To = "mshea@certobrothers.com"
    olmsg.Subject = "Report"
    olmsg.Body = "Attached is your report"
    olmsg.Attachments.Add fullFilename, olByValue
    olmsg.Send

    Set olapp = Nothing
    Set olmsg = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Oops, wait...! I had to edit that; the event name should be `BeforeClose` not `Open`.

Comment: You are a savior! I'll keep checking back here for updates!

Comment: @LouVac ok buddy, have at it. I just updated the original code in my answer above, and there's about twice as much of it now. Sorry it took so long. Had a busy week last week; the boss was on vaycay, and I was running the IT dept alone. Bin bizzy, lol. I did stray a bit from your original code, most notably I used Range.CopyFromRecordset instead of DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet. You'll have to edit what I did to fit back to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting this here to be certain @louvac sees it. I posted the code as an edit to my previous answer, but didn't hear back from him.

```
Public Function CreateExcelWorkbookWithEvents()

    'This procedure is meant to reside in a Microsoft Access code module.

    'This procedure requires two project references:
    ' 1) Microsoft Excel   XX.Y Object Library (mine is 12.0)
    ' 2) Microsoft Outlook XX.Y Object Library (mine is 12.0)
    ' 3) Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility X.Y (mine is 5.3)

    'Project references are always preferred over CreateObject() when possible, since a
    'reference allows the IntelliSense auto-complete to do its job. Otherwise, it's
    'coding blind, and that's just no fun.

    'Access variables.
    Dim acc         As Access.Application
    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsRows      As Long
    Dim sqlText     As String

    'Excel variables.
    Dim xl          As Excel.Application
    Dim wb          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wss         As Excel.Sheets
    Dim ws          As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws1         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws3         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim firstCell   As String

    'VBIDE variables.
    Dim proj        As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim comp        As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim cmod        As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim code        As String

    'Outlook variables.
    Dim olapp       As Outlook.Application
    Dim olmsg       As Outlook.MailItem

    'Other variables.
    Dim filepath        As String
    Dim filename        As String
    Dim fileext         As String
    Dim fullFilename    As String
    Dim timestamp       As String

    'Filename construction.
    filepath = "c:\windows\temp"
    filename = "MyWb"
    fileext = "xlsm"
    timestamp = VBA.Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss")
    fullFilename = filepath & "\" & filename & "_" & timestamp & "." & fileext

    'Access objects.
    Set acc = Access.Application
    Set db = acc.CurrentDb

    'Excel objects.
    Set xl = New Excel.Application

    'Create a new blank WB with one worksheet. The 'xlWBATWorksheet' parameter creates a
    'new blank workbook with only one sheet instead of the usual three. A weird side
    'effect of this is the workbook will have the name "Sheet1" instead of "Book1", but
    'otherwise it's a perfectly normal workbook.
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    'Uncomment and change text if desired.
    'xl.Caption = "Workbook Title"

    'Add & name the tabs.
    Set wss = wb.Worksheets
    Set ws1 = wss(1)
    ws1.name = "tmpDraft"
    Set ws2 = wss.Add(, wss(wss.Count), , xlWorksheet)
    ws2.name = "tmpTurn"
    Set ws3 = wss.Add(, wss(wss.Count), , xlWorksheet)
    ws3.name = "tmpFinal"
    ws1.Select 'Go back to the first sheet.

    'Loop through worksheets, use tab names for the queries, dump the data into the sheets,
    'then format them as desired.
    firstCell = "A1" 'Where to put data on each sheet.
    For Each ws In wss
        sqlText = "SELECT * FROM " & ws.name & ""
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlText, dbOpenSnapshot, dbFailOnError)
        rsRows = ws.Range(firstCell).CopyFromRecordset(rs) 'This
        Set rs = Nothing
        ws.Cells.Font.name = "Tahoma"
        ws.Cells.Font.size = 8
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Next

    'Add the event code. Build the code in a way that's easy to read. Because there are
    'embedded double-quotes in the strings, this can get messy and difficult to read.
    'So that's why VBA.Replace() is used. It makes the "code of code" much more freindly
    'to human eyes. The code that's built here is only what's between Sub...End Sub,
    'which are created automatically by CreateEventProc().
    '
    'Just as in Microsoft Word, the paragraph character indicates where a
    'hard-return should be, but something offbeat had to be used to show the double
    'quotes, so the degree symbol ° is used, that being Chr$(176). Although any
    'character(s) which the programmer desires may be used, these were chosen because
    'they do not appear as valid characters in VBA.
    '
    'Note: The section of the code below with the If-Then to detect if Excel is visible
    'are needed because the wb.Close statement further down in this subroutine cause the
    'event we just created to be trigged as if the user is attempting to exit Excel. This
    'seemed to be the simplest way to handle this, with other options such as setting
    'a global variable somehow in Excel while the code is being created, but I didn't
    'experiment with that.
    '
    code = ""
    code = code & "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)¶"
    code = code & "Dim xlapp       As Excel.Application¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgResponse As VbMsgBoxResult¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgTitle    As String¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgText     As String¶"
    code = code & "Dim msgStyle    As Long¶"
    code = code & "¶"
    code = code & "'Detect if Excel is hidden, presumably because it was created via automation¶"
    code = code & "'from another program. If so, do not prompt the user to confirm exit.¶"
    code = code & "Set xlapp = Excel.Application¶"
    code = code & "If xlapp.Visible = True Then¶"
    code = code & "    msgTitle = °Confirm Exit°¶"
    code = code & "    msgText = °Are you sure you want to exit?°¶"
    code = code & "    msgStyle = vbApplicationModal + vbExclamation + vbYesNo¶"
    code = code & "    msgResponse = MsgBox(msgText, msgStyle, msgTitle)¶"
    code = code & "    If msgResponse = vbNo Then¶"
    code = code & "        Cancel = True 'This is what cancels the Close event.¶"
    code = code & "    End If¶"
    code = code & "End If¶"
    code = code & "End Sub¶"
    code = VBA.Replace(code, "¶", vbCrLf)       'Replace the ¶ characters with hard returns.
    code = VBA.Replace(code, "°", VBA.Chr(34))  'Replace the ° characters with double quotes.

    'Dig into the VBA Project, create the event, and add the code. NOTE: There is an
    'issue with manipulating code from VBA. You can't step through those lines in debug
    'mode if you are adding code to the SAME file you're working in. For instance, if you're
    'in an XLSM file, adding code to its own ThisWorkbook module. Won't work. It causes a
    'runtime error. I think Chip Pearson mentioned it on his VBIDE pages, but I can't find it.
    Set proj = wb.VBProject                         'Grab the VBA project.
    Set comp = proj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")    'Grab the "ThisWorkbook" code module.
    Set cmod = comp.CodeModule                      'Grab the ThisWorkbook code window.
    cmod.InsertLines cmod.CountOfLines + 1, code    'Insert the code.

    'Originally CreateEventProc() was used, but it was found to pop open the VBA IDE
    'window, despite any attempt to prevent it. However, the same goal can be accomplished
    'with the regular InsertLines() function. It's all text in the IDE anyways, and how it
    'gets there doesn't matter. One need only be certain everything is spelled correctly.
    'This is the original attempt:
    'xl.vbe.MainWindow.Visible = False               'Hide the VBA editor from the user.
    'firstLine = cmod.CreateEventProc("BeforeClose", "Workbook") + 1 'Create the event.

    'Save as a macro-enabled workbook. Don't forget: each installation of Excel may need
    'the macros enabled in the security settings.
    wb.SaveAs fullFilename, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    'Not sure if this is desired.
    'xl.Visible = True

    'Clear the variables. If the 'xl' variable is not released, lost instances of Excel
    'will start to pile up in memory. They can be seen in Task Manager, but to be properly
    'identified, click View > Select Columns > Command Line > Ok. The instances of Excel
    'started from VBA will have the command line switch '/automation -Embedding' like this:
    '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /automation -Embedding
    'And even so, these instances of Excel may not unload from memory until this subroutine
    'is finished and exits. It's a fussy thing with a difficult pattern to follow. I find if
    'while devloping the code, when stepping through debug with F8, if I stop the macro
    'prematurely, the automation instances tend to stack up and need to be manually killed.
    'Otherwise, rebooting is the only way to get rid of them.
    wb.Close True
    xl.Quit
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing

    'Create the email and send it.
    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olmsg = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olmsg.To = "user@email.com"
    olmsg.Subject = "Report"
    olmsg.Body = "Attached is your report"
    olmsg.Attachments.Add fullFilename, olByValue
    olmsg.Send

    Set olapp = Nothing
    Set olmsg = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: you are the BEST! I'll see what I can do with that but it looks like it should work perfectly

Comment: Excellent. Sorry it took a few days, work got busy and I had to put it down for a bit. But the good news is, as I said previously I've been wanting to do this for my own reports & other bits.